# formstatic belongs to and active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have a problem with active admin when I try to add a new user the [image: role shows object id instead of string]

I have in roles table admin and instructor 
but how to make to display them 
this my user.rb file in admin directory

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "new user" do
      f.inputs :f_name
      f.inputs :l_name
      f.inputs :age
      f.inputs :job_title
      f.inputs :slug
      f.inputs :birthdate
      f.inputs :country
      f.inputs :role
      f.semantic_fields_for :images do |fi|
        fi.input :photo, :as => :file
      end
    end
    f.button :submit 
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks it worked when i put this function in my role model 
def to_s
        key
    end
and put this 
f.inputs :role, :collection =>  Role.all.map{ |role| [role.key, role.id]}
in user.rb in admin dir

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following:

```
 f.inputs :role, :as => :select, :collection => # write here the code produce `id`s that will be saved in database, and a string that will actually be shown on the web page.
```